# What does the phrase "red rovering" mean?

Tags: meaning, phrases, meaning-in-context

What does the phrase "red rovering" mean? Here is the context:

> Over a decade ago, Billy Bob’s career began in the corporate world before **red-rovering** to agency life.

Comment: http://www.phrases.org.uk/bulletin_board/58/messages/1125.html

Answer (score 7):

It’s from [the children’s game of Red Rover](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_Rover).

It just means he “went over” to the other team, whatever that is in this context.

Although the children’s game is innocent enough, the [Red Rover from James Fenimore Cooper’s tale](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Red_Rover) is **not** a rover in the sense of some idle roamer or wanderer, but rather *rover* in the sense of a reaver — so a pirate.  It almost asks to be taken as having some connotation of corporate raiding.

Comment: I'm intrigued by what else is implied by that choice of expression.  As you implied, the context isn't really known.

Comment: @KristinaLopez What more is implied? Considering that J.F. Cooper’s famed Red Rover was a ***reaver**-type rover*, not a ***roaming**-type rover*, perhaps the implication might be more of a predatory raider or pirate thing than someone who’s merely wandered off on walkabout one day.  Just musing here.

Comment: +1, and you beat me to it. "Red Rover, Red Rover, let Tommy come over!"

Comment: @tchrist, if I wanted to imply red-rovering, I would not assume a walkabout.  In the game, you only get to go back to your team if you break through - so what does joining the other team imply?  Weakness, concession?  hmmmm!